# TextFileReader arguments in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas IO functions, like read_csv, read_fwf, the documentation says that the optional keyword arguments are passed to TextFileReader.

```
**kwds : optional

    Optional keyword arguments can be passed to TextFileReader.
```

And then, nothing in the documentation says what the valid arguments are.

What can be passed to TextFileReader?

Comment: `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader` documentation suggests that you can pass `engine` and _other_ keywords, but it does not specify what are those keywords.

Comment: This question drives me crazy, and so far the only answer is unsatisfying.

Answer (score 1):

> the documentation says that the optional keyword arguments are passed to TextFileReader.

Well technically when you call [pandas.io.parsers.read_csv](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L438), [pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L589) or [pandas.io.parsers.read_table](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L518) the keyword args and all your other args are passed to [pandas.io.parsers._read](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L406) which in turn passes them to [pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L670).

As we can see below, the `__init__` of [pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L670) assigns some specific kwds to various instance variables and keeps anything not expected by the init method in a instance variable called `self.orig_options`.

```py
class TextFileReader(abc.Iterator):
    """
    Passed dialect overrides any of the related parser options
    """

    def __init__(self, f, engine=None, **kwds):

        self.f = f

        if engine is not None:
            engine_specified = True
        else:
            engine = "python"
            engine_specified = False
        self.engine = engine
        self._engine_specified = kwds.get("engine_specified", engine_specified)

        _validate_skipfooter(kwds)

        dialect = _extract_dialect(kwds)
        if dialect is not None:
            kwds = _merge_with_dialect_properties(dialect, kwds)

        if kwds.get("header", "infer") == "infer":
            kwds["header"] = 0 if kwds.get("names") is None else None

        self.orig_options = kwds

        # miscellanea
        self._currow = 0

        options = self._get_options_with_defaults(engine)
        options["storage_options"] = kwds.get("storage_options", None)

        self.chunksize = options.pop("chunksize", None)
        self.nrows = options.pop("nrows", None)
        self.squeeze = options.pop("squeeze", False)

        self._check_file_or_buffer(f, engine)
        self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine)

        if "has_index_names" in kwds:
            self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]

        self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
```

As far as I can find, `self.orig_options` is only ever used when the [_get_options_with_defaults](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L721) method is called. This method appears to do some more validation of the options to make sure they will work with whatever engine you are telling the reader to use.

```py
def _get_options_with_defaults(self, engine):
        kwds = self.orig_options

        options = {}

        for argname, default in parser_defaults.items():
            value = kwds.get(argname, default)

            # see gh-12935
            if argname == "mangle_dupe_cols" and not value:
                raise ValueError("Setting mangle_dupe_cols=False is not supported yet")
            else:
                options[argname] = value

        for argname, default in _c_parser_defaults.items():
            if argname in kwds:
                value = kwds[argname]

                if engine != "c" and value != default:
                    if "python" in engine and argname not in _python_unsupported:
                        pass
                    elif value == _deprecated_defaults.get(argname, default):
                        pass
                    else:
                        raise ValueError(
                            f"The {repr(argname)} option is not supported with the "
                            f"{repr(engine)} engine"
                        )
            else:
                value = _deprecated_defaults.get(argname, default)
            options[argname] = value

        if engine == "python-fwf":
            # pandas\io\parsers.py:907: error: Incompatible types in assignment
            # (expression has type "object", variable has type "Union[int, str,
            # None]")  [assignment]
            for argname, default in _fwf_defaults.items():  # type: ignore[assignment]
                options[argname] = kwds.get(argname, default)

        return options
```

If the kwds get passed all this validation, they end up in `self.options` which is used by the [_make_engine](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d65e0a3092f3c30169d0c0a3d0227e985104a56/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L936) method as the arguments to be passed to the parser engine.

```py
    def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
        mapping: Dict[str, Type[ParserBase]] = {
            "c": CParserWrapper,
            "python": PythonParser,
            "python-fwf": FixedWidthFieldParser,
        }
        if engine not in mapping:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Unknown engine: {engine} (valid options are {mapping.keys()})"
            )
        # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
        return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)
```

Now as for the question:

> What can be passed to TextFileReader?

the answer is highly depended on what engine you are using and what arguments it supports.